# Compute distance between each combination of rows in two matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I've got the following problem in Matlab:

Let's assume we have two matrices *A* and *B* with the same size, where each row (*m*) represents a dataset over time (*n*). Matrix *A* contains the reference data and Matrix *B* the data to be tested. I now want to compute the relative distance between each and every combination of rows in *A* and *B* using

```
d(m_i,m_j) = sqrt(sum((A(m_x,:)-B(m_y,:).^2))
```

Solving this via a for loop would result in

```
for m_x = 1:size(A,2)
    for m_y = 1:size(A,2)
        d(m_i,m_j) = sqrt(sum((A(m_i,:)-B(m_j,:).^2));
    end
end
```

Is there a more elegant (and maybe faster) way of doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can use `pdist2` (see [doc](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/pdist2.html)):

```
d = pdist2(A,B);
```

The entry `d(m,n)` is the distance between `A(m,:)` and `B(n,:)`.