# pdist2 in numpy? (compute pairwise distance between rows in two matrices)

Tags: python, numpy

I have an `n` by `d` matrix `U` and an `m` by `d` matrix `V`, and I want to compute the pairwise distance between each row and `U` and each row in `V`. Essentially, I want a matrix `M` such that `M[i][j] == np.linalg.norm(U[i] - V[j]) ** 2`. I have to do this computation a lot, so I want to vectorize it. Right now, it's way too slow to just use a 2d for loop. Apparently, [matlab has a way of doing this using `pdist2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19691779/2770572), but I'm not sure if there is a numpy equivalent.

Comment: @Divakar That worked like a charm. Thank you!